# PHP Selecting from various database tables and ordering

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to select data from 3 mysql database tables, tally up various results from 1 table (points), order by highest points to lowest and show only 100 results.

I have this query which I believe may be on the cusp of success but not quite.

The 3 tables are users, dealerships and sales_list.

Your assistance with achieving the above and correcting the query is appreciated.

```
$query = "  SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.sales_points 
            FROM users t1 
            JOIN dealerships t2 
            ON t1.dealership_id = t2.dealership_id 
            INNER JOIN sales_list t3 
            ON t1.users_sales_guild_id = t3.users_sales_guild_id 
            ORDER BY t3.sales_points
            LIMIT 100";
```

Comment: Try `ORDER BY t3.sales_points DESC`.

Comment: Perhaps it should be completed in 3 or 4 parts:
1. Query dealerships and users to get ids,
2. Query and loop through sales_list adding up points,
3. Generate an Array from the results,
4. Reorder the Array by total points values.

Thoughts?

Comment: . . You need only one query.  Your question doesn't explain the problem with your query.  One obvious problem is that you want the highest points, but you are ordering by the lowest.  I suspect your query has other issues.  Please edit the question with your data and the results that you want to see (and given that no one has answered this question, you could delete this one and add a more detailed question).